# How to make Master PDF Editor the default for .pdf files

Tags: pdf, master-pdf-editor

I want to make Master PDF Editor (MPE) the default for opening PDF files. I right-clicked a PDF file, chose Properties > Open With. MPE was not listed. I clicked Show Other Applications but MPE was still not on the list. I tried opening the PDF file with MPE, editing, and then closing it. MPE still did not show up.

So how do I make MPE the default program, or at least appear on the Other Programs or Show Other Programs?

Comment: Thanks for the answer --> I tried this but still can't see Master PDF Editor under Show Other Applications. I would appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 6):

If Master PDF Editor (MPE) is not listed all you need is to create a MasterPdfEditor.desktop file.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/MasterPdfEditor.desktop
```

Copy and paste the following, and then save and close the file. (Note that the *.desktop files should be in /usr/share/applications).

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Master PDF Editor
Comment=PDF and XPS files editor
Exec=/opt/master-pdf-editor/master-pdf-editor %f
Path=/opt/master-pdf-editor
Icon=/opt/master-pdf-editor/master-pdf-editor.png
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
Categories=PDF Editor;XPS Editor;Office;Utility;Text Editor;
```

**Then**

Right click on the PDF file --> Open With --> Open With Other Application

[image]

If you don't see Master PDF Editor in the list, click on Show Other Applications

[image]

Scroll down to Master PDF Editor, highlight it, and click on Use as Default.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have sufficient reputation to comment on the previous answer, but I would just like to add that for me the file was /usr/share/applications/MasterPdfEditor.desktop NOT mpe.desktop.

If you have MasterPdfEditor.desktop, just edit that.  Otherwise, you will create a file called mpe.desktop but it will not be detected by the 'Open with' dialog.

Answer (score 0):

**To set the file associations :**

1. Right Click on the file
2. Choose Properties
3. Go to the Open With tab.
4. Choose your file viewer. For eg. **Master Pdf Editor**

Now click the button, **Set as Default**

[image]

Now, when you reopen the file/application again, then it will open in your set default application.